# Overhead to sort block addresses in the multilevel indexed allocation like ext2

Tags: filesystems

I'm not familiar with details of OSs or filesytems, but I'm now studying about file allocation approaches, especially, indexed allocation that forms the basis of major Linux filesystems like ext2/3/4.

I have one question about the management of block addresses in multilevel inodes. For example, if three level is adopted, the total number of block addresses to be managed is 1024^3. But, to support the sequential access, I think all of these block addresses should be sorted, so the insertion (or deletion) of one block located in the middle of one file seems to require a very expensive computation cost because it mat need to significantly modify the three level structure. Am I right? And, is some kind of efficient sorting algorithm is used to manage a large number of block addresses?

It would be very appreciated if some of you could answer to my question.

Thanks in advance!

I would like to have a simple and intuitive answer. I couldn't find it although I checked a lot of web pages and presentation slides on the web.